# How can you assign a value to a variable if mysql does not yield any result?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

There are two databases. I am trying to see if email in the first database is also present in the second database. Here's the code that I've tried:

```
// Getting info from the first "subscribers" database.
 
$sql = "SELECT name, email, status 
        FROM subscribers 
        WHERE status='active'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    // To check if all emails in "subscribers" database are also present in "phpbb_users" database. 
    // If they are present then user type=0 otherwise user type=1.

    $subscriber_email = $row['email'];
    $forum_sql = mysqli_query($forum_link, "SELECT user_type 
                                            FROM phpbb_users 
                                            WHERE user_email='$subscriber_email'");

    while($forum_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($forum_sql)){
        $ut = $forum_row['user_type'];
        if($ut=="0"){
            $type="0";
        } else {
            $type="1";
        }
        echo $type;
    }   

    // To diplay the data from "subscribers" database.
    echo $row["name"]; 
    echo $row['email'];
}
```

The output is:

[image]

The type for onera and julian is blank because there email is not present in the phpbb_users database. How can I avoid this blank space and make it 1 or anything else. var_dump() shows nothing.

Comment: The code that outputs the list would be helpful. It's always good to indent code correctly too - it makes it far easier to digest what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple logical issue in the code with this section:

```
while($forum_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($forum_sql)){
    $ut = $forum_row['user_type'];
    if($ut=="0"){
        $type="0";
    } else {
        $type="1";
    }
    echo $type;
}
```

If the user is not in the second table, then this code will *never run*.  So `type` is never output.

Reorganise the code so that type is set by default and always output, even if there is no row in the second table:

```
$type = "1";
while($forum_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($forum_sql)) {
    $ut = $forum_row['user_type'];
    if($ut == "0"){
        $type = "0";
    }
}
echo $type;
```

Comment: Actually I tried this before posting but it did not work because I was placing echo $type; inside of the closing while }. Now I saw my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all that php code this a SQL single statement, using `exists` and a subquery:

```
select name, email, 
    exists (select 1 from phpbb_users u where u.user_email = s.email) as exists_in_phpbb
from subscribers s
where status = 'active'
```

This adds a column to the resultset called `exists_in_phpbb`, that contains `1` of the email can be found in `phpbb_users`, and `0` if it does not.

Comment: that's new to me, will try after reading a bit more on how this works, thanks

Comment: @SpeckDrip: welcome. Note that doing the whole thing in database, as shown in my answer is much more efficient than iterating in PHP and running multiple queries, as your current code does.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line..

```
echo empty($ut) ? 1 : $ut;
```

Comment: tried it before posting, it returns 1 for all cases

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (!isset($type)) {
    echo "1"
}
```

after the inner while